# While ResultSet is not executing?

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop, resultset

I am trying to call two sets of data from two different tables to display in a JTextArea (`jtaDisplay`). The first table (`emp_db`) will get the employee number, name and surname. The second table (`sec_clearance`) will get the employee security clearance level.

The method is placed in the constructor so it will execute when the frame starts up, but whenever I run the frame it does not display the data. No error messages come up and the stack trace doesn't display any error messages.

I placed a JOptionPane in various places inside the method to see where the problem lies exactly and found that the `while(rs.next())` statement is not executing as the JOptionPane displays outside the `while` statement but not inside it.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
try
        {
            String user = txtEmpTitle.getText();
            String encuser = encrypt(user); //encrypting employee number with AES to read in database
            String getEmpNum = "Select * from emp_db where emp_num = '" + encuser + "'";
            String getSecLevel = "select secLevel from sec_clearance where emp_num = '" + encuser + "'";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = (Connection)
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_database","root","pass123");
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            Statement stmt2=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getEmpNum);
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(getSecLevel);

            while(rs.next() && rs2.next())
            {
                String empNum = rs.getString("emp_num");
                String empName = rs.getString("fname");
                String empSname = rs.getString("sname");
                String empSecLevel = rs2.getString("secLevel");

                //decrypting data in database
                String decNum = EmpEditDB.decrypt(empNum);
                String decName = EmpEditDB.decrypt(empName);
                String decSname = EmpEditDB.decrypt(empSname);
                String decSecLevel = EmpEditDB.decrypt(empSecLevel);

                jtaDisplay.setText("Employee number: " + decNum + 
                        "\nEmployee name: " + decName + " " + decSname + 
                        "\nSecurity clearance: " + decSecLevel);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }
```

How can I get the code in the while statement to execute and display data in the JTextArea?

Comment: What thread does this run on? Using a swing component to display messags may or maynot work depending on that. In fact you maybe barking up the wrong tree, because code may well be executing but the gui is not updated! Why not use a simple println???

Comment: And this has ..what to do with [tag:swing]? Yeah, I get that the code is displaying to Swing components, but that seems unrelated to the actual problem. Also, don't add the tag for your IDE - that's only for problems with, or questions about, the IDE!

Comment: BTW - `jtaDisplay.setText` should probably be `jtaDisplay.append`, but again, that does not seem to be the root of the problem. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You cannot read through 2 or more result sets at the same time.  In your case, you could rewrite the SQL select to return one result set containing the employee information and the security level.

Answer (score 0):

only if you have record ,it will come into while loop.Better use preparedstatement for dynamic value setting.For debugging purpose try to print your query in debugging and copy the query and execute in sql tool for checking whether any records.

Comment: There are records in the database and I just tried using a prepared statement as you suggested and it still didn't work. I did try printing my query in debugging but it came up blank